# jqGrid wrong scroll position in RTL direction

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jqgrid

I am using jqGrid plugin `4.6`, when I set grid direction direction to `rtl` and grid `height` to (for example 200), the scroll will be shown

But the scroll positioned in the left of grid instead of its right.

Please see attached (It is in Persian).
[image]
Is there any way to fix it ?!

Comment: So thats what `rtl` means right? And its not a bug, its the feature

Comment: The grid direction is `rtl` means the grid will set all data in `rtl` how ever I expect the `rtl` grid have the scroll on its right side instead of left. Can this be done ?!

Comment: @AlirezaFattahi: I'm not use RTL myself, but the scrollbar on the left side is the standard behavior of HTML: https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/jax88z6h/. The same behavior for both `dir="rtl"` attribute or `direction: rtl` CSS. I repeat that I'm not use rtl languages myself and I don't know any country specific preferences, but the scrollbar on the left side seems to me standard for HTML with direction RTL.

Comment: @Oleg Thanks, well the browsers acts differently on `RTL`. For example in an `RTL`  page the **FireFox** sets the scroll bar on right while the **IE** puts it in the left. My question is about **Firefox**, for an RTL page, the **page** scroll bar is set on the right, while the for an RTL **grid** the scroll bar is set on the left. I have updated the picture to show two scroll bars.

Comment: @AlirezaFattahi: In my tests of https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/jax88z6h/ I have the same look in all web browsers which I have on my computer: IE11, Microsoft Edge, Firefox 44, Chrome 48.

Answer (score 1):

Well you can give a try, Since you have not posted your HTML I think you should replace the selectors correctly to your HTML.

```
#table{
    direction:ltr;        
}

#table tbody, #table thead{
    direction:rtl;
}
```

So the basic idea is, make the table `ltr` (so on overflow it scrolls as usual) then you can make the inside content like thead and tbody `rtl` (so the text is in the direction rtl). But I think the scroll bar being on the left itself would be the correct thing. But still you know whats better for your work.